# Center items that are created from an external php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table I'd like to center on my web page. The html file loads a table from a php file, but for some reason, even with center-block as a class(using bootstrap), nothing happens. The table loads fine, it's just not centered.

HTML:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){                          
    $(".mytable").load('pastmoods.php');                         
  });
</script>
<div class = "mytable center-block" style="text-align:center"></div>
```

PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM DemoUser");
$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($query);

echo "<h1>Past Moods: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
  $field = mysqli_fetch_field($query);
  echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))
{
  echo "<tr>";

  // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
  // of $row to $cell variable
  foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";    
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: Have you tried `margin:0 auto;`?

Comment: Haha...You can just add `<center>` tag between `.myTable`'s `<div>`. Try it..Or share your CSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='xxx'><tr>";
```

Try this out.

Edited as proposed by @Aashray

Comment: You should probably escape the inner double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed width for your div and use text-center bootstrap class, not the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use center at all. Stick to css. Put the table in a 'div' or 'span' and center that with css, making sure you have set the margins as mentioned by Sachi above.

Answer (score 0):

Is your table floated left or right? That could be a problem. Make sure that it has float:none on it, or has no float at all.

Also, make sure that the parent element of the table has room for the table to center within. For example if the the table and it's parent elements inside width are the same size the table won't have space to center within.

Make sure the table is not width: 100% as it will fit to its parent without centering.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would need CSS here:

```
.mytable.center-block {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is depending on what container the `<div class="mytable center-block style="text-align"></div>` is inside of.

For example, this would center your table according to the parent `div`:

HTML

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="mytable center-block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent-div {
    width: 1000px; /* Let's say for this example the parent-div is 1000px wide */
    height: 400px; /* Some height, just to give it dimension */
}

.mytable.center-block {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the table within the parent-div */
}
```

Of course, this is considering that the table is less than 1000px wide, which I am assuming for the sake of this example. Let me know if this helps.

Edit: Also to note, it is not good practice to put HTML elements below `<script>` tags. `<script>` tags ideally should be located within the header or the before the closing body tag `</body>`.